# генерация sitemap для новостного сайта

Tags: seo, индексация, sitemap

Новичок в seo, подскажите пожалуйста, есть сайт, у него есть часто обновляемая лента статей, каждая статья имеет url типа: сайт.ru/detail?id=134 и т.д. Как мне добавлять в sitemap все это? Добавлять постоянно каждый такой url , или достаточно указать /detail ?

Comment: Для начала попросить разработчиков сделать ЧПУ))

Comment: И нет, одного лишь /detail будет недостаточно

Comment: чпу сделаем, понятно что просто ?id= не очень, это кстати сильно по на индексацию влияет?

Comment: Просадки в первое время все равно будут, даже с 301 редиректом. И лучше дождаться ответа от SEOшников, я разработчик всего лишь))

Answer (score 0):

В карту сайта надо устанавливать только абсолютные (т.е. полные) УРЛ. Проверьте **[следующее высказывание Гугл об этом](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668)**:

> **Общие рекомендации по файлам Sitemap**
>
> Используйте один и тот же синтаксис при указании URL. Google будет
> сканировать их в точности по списку. Например, если сайт размещен по
> адресу https://www.example.com/, **не используйте** URL
> https://example.com/ (без www) или ./moyastranitsa.html (**относительный
> URL**).